# How to replace `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier` to `X509Certificate2`

Tags: xconnect, azure, azure-search, certificate

I'm using `Sitecore 9.2` scaled environment on Azure, and am trying to make a .Net core 2.2 project published on azure app service connects to XConnect which is also on Azure, am following this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-tutorial--1--create-a-contact-and-an-interaction.html) from Sitecore documentation.

but this time when I tried this code from this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code). To get the certificate from Azure:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                        // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                        "E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870",
                        false);
```

I **found** the certificate. but when I tried to connect using this connection string:

```
var xdbCollectionCert = "StoreName=My;StoreLocation=CurrentUser;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue={thumbprintvalue}";
var xdbClient = "{XConnectName}"
var odataEndpoint = xdbClient + "/odata";
var collectionEndpoint = xdbClient + "/configuration";
var options = CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions.Parse(xdbCollectionCert);

var certificateModifier = new CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier(options);
```

It gives an error that certificate not found, although I added the certificate in TLS and added `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`

```
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The certificate was not found. Store: My, Location: CurrentUser, FindType: FindByThumbprint, FindValue: {thumbprintValue}, InvalidAllowed: False.
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier.Process(HttpClientHandler handler)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.CreateRequestHandler()
```

Can someone please advise how can I change`CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier` to `X509Certificate2`? or why the code can not find the certificate?

Comment: Looks like code is unable to find a cert in the current user's personal store. Can you update StoreName from My to Root in your xdbCollectionCert connectionString and check?

Comment: @Surya I tried all possible combination between StoreName and StoreLocation, but it gives the same error "The certificate is not found". I can't figure out why it can't find the certificate even I added the public key certificate

Comment: @Fatemaelsayed I've looked a bit at the source code and I can't find any `CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier`, but I _can_ find a `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier`, and that one basically ends up fetching the certificate the same way you have successfully done (from what I've seen in the source). What happens if you use `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier` instead?

Comment: @GTHvidsten Its my mistake am already using `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions` I edited the question, but do you have any idea why the code can not find the certificate?

Comment: No idea. The code to fetch the certificate seems virtually identical to your uppermost code that works. I'm guessing that everything works just fine when you run things locally, and it only acts up when you're running in Azure? (therefore, no use of debugging locally)

Comment: @GTHvidsten You're right everything works fine locally, I can't figure out why it's not working when I published the code on Azure

Comment: Looking at the code I can see that `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier` inherints from `IHttpClientHandlerModifier`. Maybe you could try to create your own implementation of this interface, get the certificate in the `Process()` method using the code you know works, then set the certificate to the handler provider as input to this method: `handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual; handler.ClientCertificates.Add(yourCertificate);`.

Comment: @GTHvidsten That actually worked, I used `CertificateValidationHttpClientHandlerModifier.proccess(handler)` but I ran into `The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden` this error. I think this is because the certificate is in CurrentUser/My not trusted. Do you know how to move the certificate to CurrentUser/root or LocalMachine/Root on Azure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101650/discussion-between-gthvidsten-and-fatema-elsayed).

Comment: Hi @Fatemaelsayed - I am tryign to consume the delete API in a console app(non sitecore context) , and getting into client certificate issues on the azure app service. For now i have disabled the certificatethumprint on appservice but can you please confirm if we really need to implement a custom clienthttphandlermodifier to pick the x509 certificate from appservice or local windows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code in `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier` the certificate should have been loaded. However, you can create your own certificate handler by implementing `IHttpClientHandlerModifier`.

```
public class CustomHandler : IHttpClientHandlerModifier {
    public void Process(HttpClientHandler handler) {
        X509Certificate cert = LoadYourCertificateHere();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    }
}
```

Now you can use your own code to load the certificate in `LoadYourCertificateHere()` using code you know works. This will also give you better logging/debugging options as everything happens in your own code.